# returning null do nothing

Tags: java, io, javadoc, wav

my program is 90% done for an assignment but i keep getting one error. It says "If WavIO.read() returns null, no change should be made to the current samples array." No idea what to change. Also, Im new to writing javadocs, whats the proper way to write a javadoc for the constructors/methods and the @params etc.  Here is my code:

```
public class Sound
{   
private String fileName;
private double [] samples; 
/**
 * initializes the empty Sound array.
 */
public Sound() {
    this.samples = new double[0];
}
/**
 * Makes copy sound object of given sound.
 */
public Sound(Sound pSound) {
    double[] temp;
    temp = new double[pSound.samples.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = pSound.samples[i];
    }
    this.samples = temp;
}
/**
 * get the array of sound samples
 * @return samples
 */
public double[] get() {
    return samples;
}
/**
 * increase volume of sound by given percent
 * @param double how much to increase volume by
 */
public void increaseVol(double percent) {
    // percent = percent/100.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        samples[i] = samples[i] * (1.0 + percent);
    }
}
/**
 * reduce volume of sound by given percent
 * @param double how much to reduce volume by
 */
public void reduceVol(double percent) {
    //percent = percent/100.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        samples[i] = samples[i] * (1.0 - percent);
    }
}
/**
 * lengthen sound duration by two
 */
public void lengthen() { 
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        t[i] = samples[i];
    }
    samples = new double[t.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i++) {
        samples[i] = t[i / 2];
    } 
}
/**
 * shorten sound duration by half.
 */
public void shorten() {
    double[]t = new double[samples.length];
    if ( samples.length % 2 == 0) {
        t = new double[samples.length / 2];
    }
    else { 
        t = new double[samples.length / 2 + 1]; 
    }
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        t[i] = samples[j];
        j = j + 2;
    }
    samples = t;
}
/**
 * reverse the sound
 */
public void reverse() {
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length / 2; i++) {
        double temp = samples[i];
        samples[i] = samples[samples.length - 1 - i];
        samples[samples.length - 1 - i] = temp;
    }
}
/**
 * set array of sound samples
 */
public void set(double[] mySamples) {
    if (mySamples == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("null");
    } 
    else {
        samples = new double[mySamples.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mySamples.length; i++) {
            samples[i] = mySamples[i];
        }
    }
}    
/**
 * read a Wav file of given file name
 */
public void wavRead(String fileName) {
    this.samples = WavIO.read(fileName);
}
/**
 * save sound sample giving it a name
 */
public void wavSave(String fileName) {
    WavIO.write(fileName, samples); 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void wavRead(String fileName) {
    double[] fileContents = WavIO.read(fileName);
    if (fileContents != null) {
        this.samples = fileContents;
    }
}
```

Re your second question, I suggest you find a tutorial about Javadocs.  "How to write Javadoc" is too broad to fully answer here.